# iOS Objective C Completion Block will not return data where required from Azure Mobile Apps Framework method. Building Bundle Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, asynchronous, completion

I have been struggling with this for hours, maybe days. I need to return the results of a query into a string and have my method return the string. However, the query has to be executed with a method within MicrosoftAzure's Mobile App Sync Framework. I cannot change this method to include changes that allow me to pass the data back into a local variable string. So I'm stuck with the querywithpredicate: method only allowing void returned and all the data is sent to the completion block. I've found many block examples and tried them but none will work with the predefined method from the Azure Framework. I've also seen many examples of the blocks using data but NSLogging all my results from an nspredicate query is great for debugging but not real useful. Truly I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place because I also don't control the calling method to my azureQuery method.

A Third Party Calls -> azureQuery: (myMethod) -> azureQuery calls itemTable readWithPredicate: method in the Azure Framework.

The third party caller is waiting for the query results.

How can I return the results by allowing the block to finish its work on the query? Also keep in mind, I am building a bundle, so I may not have access to the AppDelegate Singleton Class of all iOS Apps in the future. I nee a way for azureQuery to return the data that I need from the NSPredicate query.

Things I've already tried:

1) _block NSString *data => This Failed never populated
2) created a global variable that both my method and the completion block could access => this Failed.
3) Created a while loop to check for different variables to not be empty. Loop never ended => This Failed.
4) Tried creating a block return result in my method declaration of azureQuery. This didn't achieve the desired results. It left me in another block in another method.

I need to escape the block at some point in time to store results in a NSString that can be used without block notation.

```
-(NSString*)azureQuery:(NSString *)tableName {
// Query Param
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2017-07-06T03:56:38.569+00:00"];

// convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+00:00'"];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+00:00'"];
str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dte];
dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"Date to use after formating: %@", dte);

// Create a predicate that finds items where complete is false
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt > %@", dte];

QSTodoService* serviceAzure = [[QSTodoService alloc] init];
MSTable *itemTable = [serviceAzure.client tableWithName:tableName];

__block NSString *myData;//maybe this will work
//begin query method
[itemTable readWithPredicate:predicate completion:^(MSQueryResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    //actions inside the completion block
    NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);
        } else {
            for(NSDictionary *item in result.items) {
                NSString *value = [item objectForKey:@"mbsq"];
                [stringArray addObject:value];
            }

        }
    //results of query in string
    NSString * result2 = [stringArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\r"];
    self.fName = result2;

    }];//end of completion block

while(_fName.length == 0) {
    //buy me some time for completion block to populate fName Global Variable
}
NSLog(@"Did it populate:%@",self.fName);
return myData;
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Update: I've tried to use a completion handler block but no good.

When I get back to the calling method, I run into the same problem with the completion block finishing after the return errorcode is sent.  The             results.SetAsText ( *outText2, *default_locale ); never fires in time.

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0

errorResult = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//FMScripterViewController* cmd = [[FMScripterViewController alloc] init];
//[cmd azureQuery:tableName];

    FMScripterViewController* cmd = [[FMScripterViewController alloc] init];
    [cmd azureQuery:tableName withResponseCallback:^(NSString *responseDictionary) {

        //NSLog(@"test in plugin responses %@", responseDictionary);

        fmx::TextUniquePtr outText2;
        //const char *c = [rtnString UTF8String];

        const std::string bar([responseDictionary UTF8String]);

        std::cout << "Firehouse:" << bar;

        outText2->Assign ( bar.c_str(), fmx::Text::kEncoding_UTF8 );

        std::cout << "outText2:" << &outText2;

        fmx::LocaleUniquePtr default_locale;

        results.SetAsText ( *outText2, *default_locale );

        //results.SetAsText( *result_text, dat1.GetLocale() );
    }];
});
```

## endif

```
errorResult = 0;

return errorResult;
}
```

Comment: your `azureQuery` code shouldn't return a value. It should accept a completion handler block from its caller and it can invoke that block once it has the result.

Comment: Paulw, I tried adding a completion handler to the azureQuery but it put me into another block. withCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *result))block; This I added AzureQuery but when my caller init my azureQuery all they could use was a block to see result and couldn't escape the string from the  block.

Comment: Paulw please see my new edits with the completion handler block.

Comment: Your caller is going to have to deal with the fact that the operation is asynchronous.  Asynchronous operations are very common in iOS development. Your caller can use a semaphore or dispatch group to block until the completion handler has updated some variable, but this is not recommended.

Comment: dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.bgtask", NULL);
    
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        dispatch_group_t group1 = dispatch_group_create();
            dispatch_group_enter(group1);
        
                    //execute some query mehtods

                    dispatch_group_leave(group1);
        
            //Wait for the completion block to execute before continuing script
            dispatch_group_wait(group1, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        });